# Inserting a file into Jlabel with JFileChooser

Tags: java, swing, jfilechooser

Am trying to get a file(image) to fit into a Jlabel with JFileChooser. But it enlarges the Jlabel when i insert the file.
This is a sample of my codes...

```
JFileChooser chooser = new JFileChooser();
chooser.showOpenDialog(null);
File f = chooser.getSelectedFile();
String filename = f.getAbsolutePath();
btnInsert.setText(filename);
ImageIcon icon = new ImageIcon(filename);
lblPic.setIcon(icon);
```

Comment: Yes, a JLabel will display an image at its actual size. You can use the `Image.getScaledInstance(...)` method to resize an image.

Comment: How will i do that please?.. This is a sample of my codes.........        JFileChooser chooser = new JFileChooser();
        chooser.showOpenDialog(null);
        File f = chooser.getSelectedFile();
        String filename = f.getAbsolutePath();
        btnInsert.setText(filename);
        ImageIcon icon = new ImageIcon(filename);
        lblPic.setIcon(icon);

Comment: Read the API for information on the method. Search the forum/web for examples that show you how to use the method. How you learn is up to you, but we are not here to write the code for you. ImageIcon has a method to get the Image or you can use ImageIO to read the image. Then you just invoke the above method to resize the image and recreate a new ImageIcon using the scaled image..

Comment: You can [edit] your post. Since you are new to this Web site, I have added your code to your original post.

Answer (score 0):

Try this code, it may helpful to you.

Read the picture as a BufferedImage

```
 BufferedImage img = null;
 JFileChooser chooser = new JFileChooser();
 chooser.showOpenDialog(null);
 File file = chooser.getSelectedFile();
 try {
     img = ImageIO.read(file );
 } catch (IOException e) {
     e.printStackTrace();
 }
```

Resize the BufferedImage

```
Image dimg = img.getScaledInstance(label.getWidth(), label.getHeight(), Image.SCALE_SMOOTH);
```

Make sure that the label width and height are the same proportions as the original image width and height. In other words, if the picture is 600 x 900 pixels, scale to 100 X 150. Otherwise, your picture will be distorted.

```
ImageIcon imageIcon = new ImageIcon(dimg)
```